# Testing POST #create in RSpec with nested attributes - can't get params hash correct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, controller, parameters

Have been spending some months trying to grok RSpec/TDD. Running into some challenges testing a controller with a nested attribute. I'm a bit fuzzy about how to properly set up and pass the parameters to the controller. I can build the controller so that it actually works as expected in the browser - I just can't seem to reverse engineer a test to confirm that.

Would appreciate any recommendations to a) fix the test below, and b) advise any better ways to do it (e.g. with mocks, stubs, etc).

Here's the basic model structure:

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :scholarships 
end

class Scholarship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school
end
```

I've configured the routes.rb as you'd expect, with:

```
  resources :schools do
    resources :scholarships, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  end
```

In the controller, #new and #create are pretty standard for a Rails app:

```
class ScholarshipsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @school = School.find(params[:school_id])
    @scholarship = @school.scholarships.build
  end

  def create
    @school = School.find(params[:school_id])
    @scholarship = @school.scholarships.create(scholarship_params)
    if @scholarship.save
      flash[:success] = 'Scholarship created!'
      redirect_to @school
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

    def scholarship_params
      params.require(:scholarship).permit(:name, ** Lots of params omitted for brevity **, 
        :notes, school: [:id])
    end
end
```

The spec is where I can't seem to figure things out. For spec/controllers/scholarships_controller_spec.rb:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe ScholarshipsController, type: :controller do
  describe 'POST #create' do
    context 'with valid attributes' do
      before :each do
        @school = create(:school)
        @scholarship = @school.scholarships.create(FactoryGirl.build(:scholarship).attributes) 
      end

      it 'receives :save' do
        post :create, { scholarship: @scholarship.attributes, school: @school.id }
        expect(@scholarship).to receive(:save)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When I run that test, I get the following error:

```
Failures:

  1) ScholarshipsController POST #create with valid attributes receives :save
     Failure/Error: post :create, scholarship: { attributes: @scholarship.attributes, school: @school.id }      #school_id: @school.id, scholarship: @scholarship
 ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"scholarships",
:scholarship=>{"id"=>"1", "name"=>"Dynamic Metrics Director Scholarship", *** Lots of parameters omitted for brevity ***
, "school_id"=>"2"}, :school=>"2"}
```

The parameters look correct to me. there's a set of attributes for the scholarship, and for the school. But the routing isn't working. I've tried a dozen different ways to try and get this to work. Heartened that I'm apparently passing a (more or less correct) parameters hash, but can't figure out quite where I'm going wrong.

****** EDIT ******

Updated in response to an answer posted below.
Changed the syntax of the spec as suggested by Srdjan:

```
 it 'receives :save' do
    post :create, "schools/#{@school.id}/scholarships", { scholarship: @scholarship.attributes, school_id: @school.id }
    expect(@scholarship).to receive(:save)
  end
```

This changes the error message. I assume that indicates that the parameters are being passed correctly, since it's no longer throwing an error related to routes/params..? Error message is:

```
1) ScholarshipsController POST #create with valid attributes receives :save
     Failure/Error: expect(@scholarship).to receive(:save)
       (#<Scholarship:0x007fe293b02598>).save(*(any args))
           expected: 1 time with any arguments
           received: 0 times with any arguments
```

Just for good measure, here are the relevant routes, which I hadn't posted previously:

```
  school_scholarships POST   /schools/:school_id/scholarships(.:format)     scholarships#create
new_school_scholarship GET    /schools/:school_id/scholarships/new(.:format) scholarships#new
    school_scholarship DELETE /schools/:school_id/scholarships/:id(.:format) scholarships#destroy
```

Comment: If you run rake routes, do you see a route that matches where you are posting to? What have you put in the form_for? Rails is expecting a nested route.

Answer (score 1):

In your test, you're POST-ing to the wrong route. As setup in `routes.rb`, scholarship resources do not exist out of the context of a school resource.

In order to fix this, you have to answer a question: "Does it make sense for a user to access a scholarship record without having to specify a school?"

If the answer is yes, you can either copy the `scholarships` route and paste them outside of the `schools` resource block. This way, you can have access to scholarships without having to specify a school, but also with specifying a school.

If the answer to the question is no, then you need to fix your test as such:

`it 'receives :save' do
  post :create, "schools/#{@school.id}/scholarhips", { scholarship: @scholarship.attributes, school_id: @school.id }
  expect(@scholarship).to receive(:save)
end`

Comment: Srdjan, that changes the error message - so some progress! However, now it shows the error: `Failure/Error: expect(@scholarship).to receive(:save) (#<Scholarship:0x007fe293b02598>).save(*(any args)) expected: 1 time with any arguments received: 0 times with any arguments` Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: Yes, since you're making an expectation, that needs to come *before* the post command.